# Inserting a NULL/Empty value into real field Postgres SQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psql

I have an insert string into my table, but some values are empty which isn't an issue as these values should be intentionally left blank. I'm looking for a smart way to handle this without needing to rewrite my insert string....its is much longer than this below, but the below shows the two fields which are defined as `real` data types.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_" + country + " (lat, lon) VALUES (%s, %s)" , (loc['LAT'], loc['LON'], ))
```

So sometimes

`loc['LAT']` will be `''` and other times e.g `'54.44'`
`loc['LON']` will be `''` and other times e.g. `'53.46'`

If these are blank, I get the following error:

```
pg8000.errors.ProgrammingError: ('ERROR', '22P02', 'invalid input syntax for type real: ""')
```

Comment: try replacing `loc['LAT']` with `loc['LAT'] or 'NULL'` and similarly for `loc['LON']`

Comment: @behzad.nouri I already tried this, I get: pg8000.errors.ProgrammingError: ('ERROR', '22P02', 'invalid input syntax for type real: "NULL"')

Comment: check the schema, and see if those columns can have null values

Comment: Have you tried something like `VALUES (nullif(%s,''), nullif(%s,''))` in the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @Igor your comment deserves to be an answer, if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those columns accept `null`

```
cursor.execute("""
    insert into table_" + country + " (lat, lon) values (%s, %s)
    """ , (loc['LAT'] or None, loc['LON'] or None)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the empty character string to convey the idea that there is no data present in one row  of this column.  The empty character string is not a valid real number.  That is why you are getting the error.

You need to allow NULLs in this column, and alter your input so that when the value is missing, it supplies NULL (without any quotes) instead of a real number.

However, if you allow NULLS, you need to realize that if you do statistical summaries on this column, the way SQL processes NULLs will introduce strange consequences in your output.  If those consequences are unfortunate, you need a different approach.

Comment: I understand this, but I have an existing table as reference with the same column types that has nothing it it for these real types. But looking at the data types they are identical.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "nothing".